# how to refresh a windows app page

Tags: windows-phone-8

I created a window app in which one of my page i.e 'A' shows routing directions between two points on map. Now in this page i am passing the lat and long of my current location from the previous page i.e 'B' by query string. After getting the lat and long from page 'B' I am calling my service to get the list of nearest CNG stations along with their latitude and longitude and then populate that list in my listpicker on page 'A'. Initially when we navigate to our page 'A' our map shows routing distance between my location and the first list item. Also on the selection change of listpicker i am populating the routing distance and show it in my map.

Issue- now my Requirement is to refresh this page.And the whole process should repeat in the same way as described above. Please provide me some ideas on how to move ahead with this requirement as i am new to windows app development . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Once you have navigated to your new Page here you can start a Dispatcher time that checks on periodic interval Here you can get the new latitude and longitude and update your UI accordingly. Make sure you stop the dispatcher before you navigate again from this page.